# Linux Kernel Messages: ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }

Tags: linux, sata, kernel

I am receiving a lot of these messages.  Is my HD going to die tomorrow morning?

```
ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
ata1: device not ready (errno=-16), forcing hardreset
ata1: soft resetting link
ata1: clearing spurious IRQ
ata1: clearing spurious IRQ
ata1: clearing spurious IRQ
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/33
ata1: EH complete
ata1.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xa0)
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
ata1.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 0
         cdb 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
         res 51/20:03:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x5 (timeout)
```

Comment: Your drive is already close to dead.  I hope you have good backups, because it is a bit late now to do much about it.

Comment: Yeah this definitely a terminally ill drive. Grab your data while you still can.

Comment: possible duplicate (at least, similar symptom): http://superuser.com/questions/121391/sata-drives-or-chipset-throwing-drdy-err-and-icrc-abrt

Comment: Try to replace hdd cable, sometimes it helps

Answer (score 2):

I also wanted to add, there is an official Ubuntu bug located at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/530649

(Edit: fixed broken link)

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be related to the SATA chipset ?

[SATA drives or chipset throwing DRDY ERR and ICRC ABRT](https://superuser.com/questions/121391/sata-drives-or-chipset-throwing-drdy-err-and-icrc-abrt)

Answer (score -1):

My 2 WD800JD's had a similar Exception...Emask...0x6...frozen issue. During kernel compilation it would happen maybe 20 times.
After adding "libata.force=noncq,norst" parameter the errors seem to be gone