# Testing if SATA DRDY errors are from the controller or the drive - without swapping drives

Tags: linux, hard-drive, sata

I have a six year old desktop system where the hard drive has recently started throwing these errors (running in Linux - Debian Jessie):

`[12222.788128] ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[12222.788129] ata3.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[12222.788139] ata3: soft resetting link
[12222.960980] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/33
[12222.961005] ata3: EH complete
[12231.184057] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6
[12231.184065] ata3.00: BMDMA stat 0x26
[12231.184070] ata3.00: failed command: READ DMA
[12231.184080] ata3.00: cmd c8/00:00:e7:27:c8/00:00:00:00:00/ef tag 0 dma 131072 in res 51/84:ef:e7:27:c8/84:01:0f:00:00/ef Emask 0x30 (host bus error)`

I understand that this can either be the result of a failing SATA controller or a failing hard drive.  I don't have access to any other system handy.  Is there any easy way to test if the failure is in the drive or in the controller without having to swap the drive into another computer?  I'd like to do that test before ordering a new hard drive.

Comment: Did you consider checking with SMART?

Comment: There is no way to determine if the controller or the drive is to blame, if your not willing, to try the drive in another system or try a different drive in the same system.

Comment: *"I understand that this can either be the result of a failing SATA controller or a failing hard drive."* -- You understand incorrectly. Those are not the only possibilities.  See http://superuser.com/questions/641219/possibly-a-dying-hard-drive-but-reads-writes-work-unsure-about-log-entries/642771#642771