# Can a faulty SATA cable cause erroneous SMART test results?

Tags: smart

Is it possible for a SMART self-test to fail because of a faulty SATA cable? Or does the test happen entirely inside of the drive?

Comment: how's it failing?

Comment: The HDD firmware determines if the S.M.A.R.T self-test is passing or failing.  The tests are primarly independant of the SATA cable.  If you suspect a bad cable you should still replace the cable obviously.

Comment: No. Yes.  SATA interface errors are reported distinctly from drive/media errors. See http://superuser.com/questions/641219/possibly-a-dying-hard-drive-but-reads-writes-work-unsure-about-log-entries/642771#642771