# How do I reformat a Bitlockered SSD that has a CRC error

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, crc

I have a WD SSD that was bitlockered. I do not care about the data.

When I try to reformat or diskpart clean, I get a CRC error.

However, It shows up in drives and partitions fine, CrystalDisk reports it as fine, Stablebit scanner did a full sector scan, and its fine.

Are there any other steps which could be taken to get this drive back into a usable state?

Comment: Did the StableBit "scanner" perform a write test? I'm not convinced it even does anything useful to SSDs (as they do not have the fixed 1:1 mapping of LBA-to-location that HDDs have; the firmware of an SSD is free to write stuff anywhere) but it sounds like the SSD just isn't accepting regular writes properly anymore (repartitioning does not do anything special, it just writes some data). Do you know whether BitLocker was used in "hardware" mode; does any software report "TCG OPAL" being enabled for the disk?

Comment: Can you try `clean all` in `diskpart` that should (try to) correct bad sectors if there are. Also it'd be better if you can note the exact error it gives you.

Comment: You might also try free DiskGenius: https://www.diskgenius.com/ . Delete all partitions, click "Save All" to commit change, create new partition(s), and  click "Save All" to commit change. If that does *not* work, the SSD is likely no longer writable -- i.e., dead.

Comment: @YisroelTech clean all says : "DiskPart has encountered an error: Data error (cyclic redundancy check). See the System Event Log for more information." . Event log says "The device, \Device\Harddisk6\DR6, has a bad block."

Comment: @user1686 I do not recall if bitlocker was hardware mode or whatnot.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I will try diskgenius

Comment: @DrMoishePippik when trying to save the partition deletes, genius says the following, so looks like Im dead.

Write Sector Error! Disk: HD6:WDCWDBNCE2500PNC(233GB) From Sector: 0. 1 Sector(s) Total. (Err:23 Data error (cyclic redundancy check).)

Comment: **1)** Is there more than one partition? If yes, try deletion of one partition at a time and see if it's only one with the issue. **2)** Can you run `chkdsk /f` on all the partitions? **3)** Maybe try using [Victoria](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/victoria_for_windows.html) to find the ad block and cut out/remap that the disk shouldn't use it.

Comment: Check SMART, for example Victoria for Windows.

Comment: Do not conflate CRC with ECC. Assuming the error messages are accurate, "*CRC errors*" are more likely to pertain to the SATA interface rather than the connected drive.  The SATA interface uses a CRC to validate packet integrity. Storage drives use ECC (such as Fire or Hamming or BCH codes) to validate sector integrity (and possibly correct some bits). See https://superuser.com/questions/641219/possibly-a-dying-hard-drive-but-reads-writes-work-unsure-about-log-entries/642771#642771