# SATA errors for SSD with new mainboard, works fine with old one

Tags: ssd, bios, motherboard, sata

My $old system works perfectly fine. Then I upgraded the mainboard+CPU to $new and suddenly I can no longer boot from my SSD. The GRUB bootloader stops sometimes at "GRUB", "GRUB loading" or "Welcome to GRUB!" messages.
I then booted from a Grml USB stick. Worked fine but when I tried to access the SSD I got lots of error messages in the kernel logs (see below) and could not access it properly.

When I switch back to the $old mainboard, everything works fine.
I also changed the power supply to a totally oversized 850W one in case the new boards needed more power, changed all power and sata cables to new ones and of course tried different SATA ports. The result is still the same, it works with $old but not with $new.

Then I even bought a new mainboard $new2 and even then I get the very same error messages!

What can cause this?

```
$old hardware:
  Mainboard: Gigabyte GA-Z370-HD3P
  CPU: Intel Core i5-6500
  RAM: GSkill F4-2133C15S-8GNT Memory D4 2133 8GB
  GPU: NVidia GForce RTX 4060
  SSD: 256GB TOSHIBA HG5d Series SSD (THNSNH256GBST); SATA 6Gbit/s (SATA III); 2,5"
  M.2: 1TB GIGABYTE GP-GSM2NE3100TNTD
  BIOS: SATA set to AHCI; Compatibility Support Mode (CSM) on with SATA set to "legacy"

$new hardware:
  Mainboard: ASRock B760M Pro RS/D4
  CPU: Intel Core i5-12400F
  BIOS: SATA set to AHCI; Compatibility Support Mode (CSM) on with SATA set to "legacy"

$new2 hardware:
  Mainboard: Gigabyte B760 Gaming X DDR4
  CPU: Intel Core i5-12400F
  BIOS: SATA set to AHCI; Compatibility Support Mode (CSM) on with SATA set to "legacy"
```

The error messages I was able to capture with the USB Grml rescue system:

```
[  177.390760] ata5: hard resetting link
[  177.706269] ata5: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[  177.708269] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/33
[  177.708296] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] tag#2 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  177.708303] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] tag#2 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[  177.708308] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] tag#2 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[  177.708312] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 01 0a 00 00 0a 00 00
[  177.708315] I/O error, dev sda, sector 68096 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 21 prio class 2
[  177.708364] ata5: EH complete
[  177.754713] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x10000 SErr 0x280100 action 0x6 frozen
[  177.754725] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x09000000, interface fatal error
[  177.754728] ata5: SError: { UnrecovData 10B8B BadCRC }
[  177.754737] ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  177.754740] ata5.00: cmd 60/08:80:30:0b:01/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 50/00:80:30:0b:01/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  177.754753] ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
[  177.754761] ata5: hard resetting link
 ...
[  179.657332] I/O error, dev sda, sector 100352 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 2
[  179.657344] ata5: EH complete
[  179.742717] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0xc0000 SErr 0x280100 action 0x6 frozen
[  179.742729] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[  179.742733] ata5: SError: { UnrecovData 10B8B BadCRC }
[  179.742742] ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  179.742744] ata5.00: cmd 60/00:90:00:96:01/0a:00:00:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq dma 1310720 in
                        res 50/00:90:00:96:01/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  179.742758] ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
[  179.742762] ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  179.742764] ata5.00: cmd 60/00:98:00:a0:01/0a:00:00:00:00/40 tag 19 ncq dma 1310720 in
                        res 50/00:90:00:96:01/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  179.742773] ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
[  179.742779] ata5: hard resetting link
```

Some more information from the rescue stick Linux:

```
# lsscsi
[4:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      TOSHIBA THNSNH25 N101  /dev/sda 
[7:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH24NSD1  LE00  /dev/sr0 
[8:0:0:0]    disk    USB      Disk 3.0         2.00  /dev/sdb 
[N:0:1:1]    disk    GIGABYTE GP-GSM2NE3100TNTD__1              /dev/nvme0n1

# lsscsi -C
[0]    ahci          
[1]    ahci          
[2]    ahci          
[3]    ahci          
[4]    ahci          
[5]    ahci          
[6]    ahci          
[7]    ahci          
[8]    usb-storage   
[N:0]  /dev/nvme0  GIGABYTE GP-GSM2NE3100TNTD        SN204308901495      EDFM60.0
```

P.S.: As I do not dare to make my old SSD unusable by trying something like MBR2GPT conversion, my next steps would be to buy a new m.2 disk and do a new installation of Windows and Linux with GPT partitioning. But still it bugs me that I have no clue why it does not work with the new mainboards!

Comment: Error messages that mention "BadCRC*" are referring to a SATA connection issue rather than a drive issue. The SATA interface uses CRC for its message packets, whereas the storage drive uses ECC to validate sector data. See https://superuser.com/questions/641219/possibly-a-dying-hard-drive-but-reads-writes-work-unsure-about-log-entries/642771#642771