# What can cause a HDD to unmount itself?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, sata

I have an i7-8700K PC that I want to turn into a PLEX media server (with more plans down the line).

It has a 512 GB SSD for OS stuff, an 8 TB HDD for game stuff, and in April of 2023 I installed a 14 TB WD RED NAS HDD Model WDC WD140EFGX-68B0GN0 (85.00A85) for PLEX stuff.

Performance under Windows was very spotty, so earlier this week I backed everything up and installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Immediately there were problems with the disk unmounting itself as I was updating stuff in PLEX, like changing posters or sort names. I followed [this guide](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-automount-a-drive-in-linux-the-gui-way-with-gnome/) to automount both of my data HDDs. I was able to watch my media, but writing seems to make it unmount and remount itself, at which point I just reboot to get it to function again.

Since everything was already backed up I figured I might just reformat the drive to see what happens. That errors out with an I/O error during read (g-bd-part-error-quark, 2). Tried formatting with the option to erase the disk and that errors out (udisk-error-quark, 0)
SMART Data & Self-tests run without error and say the disk is OK, so I'm starting to suspect a cable or motherboard issue?

---

**Edit**: dmsg clip.

```
[93499.958041] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD140EFGX-68 0A85 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[93499.958280] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[93499.958394] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 27344764928 512-byte logical blocks: (14.0 TB/12.7 TiB)
[93499.958397] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[93499.958410] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[93499.958413] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[93499.958432] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[93499.958454] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes
[93500.083773] audit: type=1107 audit(1704042773.963:194): pid=767 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.3" mask="receive" pid=6414 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=796 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[93501.950476]  sdb: sdb1
[93501.950887] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[93645.985649] audit: type=1107 audit(1704042919.864:195): pid=767 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.3" mask="receive" pid=6414 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=796 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[93676.266183] audit: type=1107 audit(1704042950.144:196): pid=767 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.3" mask="receive" pid=6414 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=796 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[93691.125487] audit: type=1107 audit(1704042965.000:197): pid=767 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.3" mask="receive" pid=6414 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=796 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[97124.049656] audit: type=1107 audit(1704046397.873:198): pid=767 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.3" mask="receive" pid=6414 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=796 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[97124.184109] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x580000 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen
[97124.184129] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[97124.184136] ata4: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }
[97124.184148] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[97124.184154] ata4.00: cmd 61/40:98:00:08:00/05:00:00:00:00/40 tag 19 ncq dma 688128 out
                        res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97124.184179] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[97124.184187] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[97124.184192] ata4.00: cmd 61/c0:a0:40:0d:00/02:00:00:00:00/40 tag 20 ncq dma 360448 out
                        res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97124.184212] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[97124.184220] ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[97124.184225] ata4.00: cmd 60/08:b0:70:fe:df/00:00:5d:06:00/40 tag 22 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97124.184246] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[97124.184255] ata4: hard resetting link
[97124.498951] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[97124.503378] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[97124.503388] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[97124.516099] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[97124.516106] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[97124.523018] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[97124.523078] scsi_io_completion_action: 2 callbacks suppressed
[97124.523082] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#22 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[97124.523085] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#22 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[97124.523087] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#22 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[97124.523090] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#22 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 06 5d df fe 70 00 00 00 08 00 00
[97124.523091] blk_print_req_error: 252 callbacks suppressed
[97124.523092] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 27344764528 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[97124.523101] ata4: EH complete
[97124.576134] ata4.00: sense data available but port frozen
[97124.576138] ata4.00: sense data available but port frozen
[97124.576139] ata4.00: sense data available but port frozen
[97124.576140] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x830000 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen
[97124.576144] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[97124.576145] ata4: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }
[97124.576148] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[97124.576150] ata4.00: cmd 61/c0:80:40:0d:00/02:00:00:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq dma 360448 out
                        res 43/84:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97124.576155] ata4.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[97124.576157] ata4.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[97124.576158] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[97124.576160] ata4.00: cmd 61/40:88:00:08:00/05:00:00:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq dma 688128 out
                        res 43/84:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97124.576164] ata4.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[97124.576166] ata4.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[97124.576167] ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[97124.576168] ata4.00: cmd 60/08:b8:70:fe:df/00:00:5d:06:00/40 tag 23 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 43/84:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97124.576173] ata4.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[97124.576174] ata4.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[97124.576177] ata4: hard resetting link
[97124.891437] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[97124.894884] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[97124.894888] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[97124.909089] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[97124.909104] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[97124.916392] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[97124.916437] ata4: EH complete
[97124.980135] ata4.00: sense data available but port frozen
[97124.980138] ata4.00: sense data available but port frozen
[97124.980139] ata4.00: sense data available but port frozen
[97124.980141] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0xe000000 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen
[97124.980145] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[97124.980147] ata4: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }
[97124.980150] ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[97124.980151] ata4.00: cmd 60/08:c8:70:fe:df/00:00:5d:06:00/40 tag 25 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 43/84:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97124.980157] ata4.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[97124.980159] ata4.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[97124.980161] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[97124.980162] ata4.00: cmd 61/40:d0:00:08:00/05:00:00:00:00/40 tag 26 ncq dma 688128 out
                        res 43/84:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97124.980168] ata4.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[97124.980169] ata4.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[97124.980171] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[97124.980172] ata4.00: cmd 61/c0:d8:40:0d:00/02:00:00:00:00/40 tag 27 ncq dma 360448 out
                        res 43/84:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97124.980177] ata4.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[97124.980178] ata4.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[97124.980181] ata4: hard resetting link
[97125.295248] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[97125.299485] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[97125.299498] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[97125.312325] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[97125.312330] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[97125.319372] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[97125.319389] ata4: EH complete
[97125.368056] ata4.00: sense data available but port frozen
[97125.368061] ata4.00: sense data available but port frozen
[97125.368062] ata4.00: sense data available but port frozen
[97125.368065] ata4: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
[97125.368067] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0xe00 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen
[97125.368072] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[97125.368075] ata4: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }
[97125.368081] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[97125.368084] ata4.00: cmd 61/c0:48:40:0d:00/02:00:00:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq dma 360448 out
                        res 43/84:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97125.368096] ata4.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[97125.368099] ata4.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[97125.368103] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[97125.368106] ata4.00: cmd 61/40:50:00:08:00/05:00:00:00:00/40 tag 10 ncq dma 688128 out
                        res 43/84:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97125.368114] ata4.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[97125.368117] ata4.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[97125.368119] ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[97125.368121] ata4.00: cmd 60/08:58:70:fe:df/00:00:5d:06:00/40 tag 11 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 43/84:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97125.368128] ata4.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[97125.368130] ata4.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[97125.368133] ata4: hard resetting link
[97125.683065] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[97125.686621] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[97125.686628] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[97125.699346] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[97125.699351] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[97125.706333] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[97125.706349] ata4: EH complete
[97125.768165] ata4.00: sense data available but port frozen
[97125.768178] ata4.00: sense data available but port frozen
[97125.768185] ata4.00: sense data available but port frozen
[97125.768193] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x60000001 SErr 0x400101 action 0x6 frozen
[97125.768211] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[97125.768221] ata4: SError: { RecovData UnrecovData Handshk }
[97125.768238] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[97125.768246] ata4.00: cmd 61/c0:00:40:0d:00/02:00:00:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq dma 360448 out
                        res 43/84:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97125.768283] ata4.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[97125.768294] ata4.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[97125.768307] ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[97125.768315] ata4.00: cmd 60/08:e8:70:fe:df/00:00:5d:06:00/40 tag 29 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 43/84:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97125.768350] ata4.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[97125.768359] ata4.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[97125.768371] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[97125.768380] ata4.00: cmd 61/40:f0:00:08:00/05:00:00:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq dma 688128 out
                        res 43/84:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97125.768412] ata4.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[97125.768421] ata4.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[97125.768435] ata4: hard resetting link
[97126.087395] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[97126.092560] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[97126.092582] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[97126.107211] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[97126.107233] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[97126.114365] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[97126.114406] ata4: EH complete
[97126.180190] ata4.00: sense data available but port frozen
[97126.180193] ata4.00: sense data available but port frozen
[97126.180194] ata4.00: sense data available but port frozen
[97126.180197] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x700 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen
[97126.180201] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[97126.180203] ata4: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }
[97126.180206] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[97126.180208] ata4.00: cmd 61/40:40:00:08:00/05:00:00:00:00/40 tag 8 ncq dma 688128 out
                        res 43/84:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97126.180215] ata4.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[97126.180217] ata4.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[97126.180219] ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[97126.180221] ata4.00: cmd 60/08:48:70:fe:df/00:00:5d:06:00/40 tag 9 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 43/84:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97126.180227] ata4.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[97126.180229] ata4.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[97126.180231] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[97126.180232] ata4.00: cmd 61/c0:50:40:0d:00/02:00:00:00:00/40 tag 10 ncq dma 360448 out
                        res 43/84:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97126.180238] ata4.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[97126.180240] ata4.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[97126.180243] ata4: hard resetting link
[97126.495050] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[97126.498203] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[97126.498207] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[97126.512023] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[97126.512041] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[97126.519095] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[97126.519157] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=2s
[97126.519168] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
[97126.519179] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 Add. Sense: Scsi parity error
[97126.519187] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#8 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 05 40 00 00
[97126.519191] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2048 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 168 prio class 2
[97126.519207] buffer_io_error: 270721 callbacks suppressed
[97126.519211] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 256, lost async page write
[97126.519236] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 257, lost async page write
[97126.519248] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 258, lost async page write
[97126.519259] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 259, lost async page write
[97126.519272] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 260, lost async page write
[97126.519283] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 261, lost async page write
[97126.519296] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 262, lost async page write
[97126.519307] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 263, lost async page write
[97126.519321] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 264, lost async page write
[97126.519334] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 265, lost async page write
[97126.519876] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#10 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=2s
[97126.519885] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#10 Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
[97126.519894] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#10 Add. Sense: Scsi parity error
[97126.519901] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#10 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0d 40 00 00 02 c0 00 00
[97126.519906] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 3392 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 88 prio class 2
[97126.520254] ata4: EH complete
[97126.522591] audit: type=1107 audit(1704046400.345:199): pid=767 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.3" mask="receive" pid=6414 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=796 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[97345.880263] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x52 SAct 0x2000000 SErr 0x400c01 action 0x6 frozen
[97345.880270] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[97345.880272] ata4: SError: { RecovData Proto HostInt Handshk }
[97345.880276] ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[97345.880278] ata4.00: cmd 60/08:c8:f0:ff:df/00:00:5d:06:00/40 tag 25 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x52 (ATA bus error)
[97345.880285] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[97345.880289] ata4: hard resetting link
[97346.195537] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[97346.195588] ata4.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)
[97346.195596] ata4.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
[97351.232394] ata4: hard resetting link
[97351.547670] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[97351.550966] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[97351.550969] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[97351.564353] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[97351.564357] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[97351.571630] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[97351.571676] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#25 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=5s
[97351.571679] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#25 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[97351.571682] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#25 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[97351.571684] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#25 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 06 5d df ff f0 00 00 00 08 00 00
[97351.571686] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 27344764912 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[97351.571696] ata4: EH complete
[97351.860433] ata4: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[97351.860444] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x80002000 SErr 0x400100 action 0x6 frozen
[97351.860458] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[97351.860465] ata4: SError: { UnrecovData Handshk }
[97351.860477] ata4.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[97351.860483] ata4.00: cmd 60/08:68:70:fe:df/00:00:5d:06:00/40 tag 13 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97351.860508] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[97351.860516] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[97351.860522] ata4.00: cmd 61/18:f8:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 31 ncq dma 12288 out
                        res 40/00:ff:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[97351.860543] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[97351.860553] ata4: hard resetting link
[97354.072047] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
[97354.083889] ata4: hard resetting link
[97356.295779] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
[97356.307148] ata4: hard resetting link
[97358.513640] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
[97358.513657] ata4.00: disable device
[97358.513692] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#13 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=6s
[97358.513703] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#13 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[97358.513711] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#13 Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, hard reset required
[97358.513719] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#13 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 06 5d df fe 70 00 00 00 08 00 00
[97358.513724] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 27344764528 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[97358.513768] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#31 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=6s
[97358.513775] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#31 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[97358.513782] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#31 Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, hard reset required
[97358.513789] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#31 CDB: Write(16) 8a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 00
[97358.513793] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 3 prio class 2
[97358.513804] buffer_io_error: 246 callbacks suppressed
[97358.513808] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, lost async page write
[97358.513829] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1, lost async page write
[97358.513838] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 2, lost async page write
[97358.513855] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[97358.513857] ata4: EH complete
[97358.513865] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 27344764904 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 3 prio class 2
[97358.513874] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 27344764528 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[97358.513883] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3418095566, async page read
[97358.513888] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3418095613, lost async page write
[97358.513904] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3418095614, lost async page write
[97358.513916] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3418095615, lost async page write
[97358.513917] ata4.00: detaching (SCSI 3:0:0:0)
[97358.521653] device offline error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 2
[97358.521670] device offline error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
[97358.521674] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[97358.600557] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[97359.240549] ata4: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[97359.245316] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[97359.245332] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[97359.245799] ata4.00: ATA-9: WDC WD140EFGX-68B0GN0, 85.00A85, max UDMA/133
[97359.252105] ata4.00: 27344764928 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32), AA
[97359.252110] ata4.00: Features: NCQ-sndrcv NCQ-prio
[97359.257781] ata4.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00(SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[97359.257785] ata4.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00(DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[97359.264753] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[97359.268872] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[97360.526035] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD140EFGX-68 0A85 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[97360.526893] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[97360.526930] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] 27344764928 512-byte logical blocks: (14.0 TB/12.7 TiB)
[97360.526945] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
[97360.526969] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
```

Comment: Since you're getting disk errors, suspect the HDD. You might remove *all* partitions from it, then create a single partition and format it. If that fails, the disk is likely the cause.

Comment: Have you looked at the kernel log `dmesg` yet?

Comment: Does the system boot and run without the HDDs physically connected?

Comment: It should, the OS is all on an SSD

Comment: Pulled the power cable from both HDDs and it booted just fine.

Comment: Since I was already in the case when I reattached the power cables I moved the SATA cable to a different port on the Motherboard.  I've been able to complete the format and partitioning, set it up to automount, and am currently restoring from backup.

Comment: A lot of those log entries are for SATA (the interface rather than the storage drive) errors. See https://superuser.com/questions/641219/possibly-a-dying-hard-drive-but-reads-writes-work-unsure-about-log-entries/642771#642771

Answer (score 3):

I moved the SATA cable from port 2 to port 4 on my motherboard and that allowed me to complete the format and partitioning, set up an automount for the new volume, and I've been successfully writing to it from my backup for the past 45 minutes without an error showing up in the dmesg.

I feel confident in stating that, while not the most likely culprit, motherboard issues can cause an HDD to frequently unmount itself.

Comment: *Performance under Windows was very spotty* - Perhaps the Windows problems were related to port 2 as well.

Comment: It's not the disk "unmounting itself", it's the kernel deciding it can't work with the disk (reliably) and dropping it. See the `[97359.268872] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk` in your log.