# Interpreting dmesg output: Drive failure imminent or sys admin error?

Tags: hard-drive, dmesg, smartctl

Last week I swapped out a 1TB drive for a 2TB drive I have lying around.  I now get the following in my `dmesg` output.

```
[Fri Feb 16 16:15:48 2024] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x20000 SErr 0x2c0100 action 0x6 frozen
[Fri Feb 16 16:15:48 2024] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[Fri Feb 16 16:15:48 2024] ata5: SError: { UnrecovData CommWake 10B8B BadCRC }
[Fri Feb 16 16:15:48 2024] ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[Fri Feb 16 16:15:48 2024] ata5.00: cmd 60/00:88:00:cb:b6/01:00:33:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq dma 131072 in
                                    res 40/00:8c:00:cb:b6/00:00:33:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[Fri Feb 16 16:15:48 2024] ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
[Fri Feb 16 16:15:48 2024] ata5: hard resetting link
[Fri Feb 16 16:15:49 2024] ata5: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[Fri Feb 16 16:15:49 2024] ata5.00: ATA Identify Device Log not supported
[Fri Feb 16 16:15:49 2024] ata5.00: ATA Identify Device Log not supported
[Fri Feb 16 16:15:49 2024] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[Fri Feb 16 16:15:49 2024] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#17 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[Fri Feb 16 16:15:49 2024] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#17 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[Fri Feb 16 16:15:49 2024] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#17 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[Fri Feb 16 16:15:49 2024] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#17 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 33 b6 cb 00 00 01 00 00
[Fri Feb 16 16:15:49 2024] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 867617536 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
[Fri Feb 16 16:15:49 2024] ata5: EH complete
```

The messages appears only twice since my last reboot and the two instances are back to back.

Here's the output from `smartctl -a /dev/sdc

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.15.0-94-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Caviar Black
Device Model:     WDC WD2002FAEX-007BA0
Serial Number:    WD-WCAY01480310
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 25db1f3a6
Firmware Version: 05.01D05
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Feb 19 16:34:38 2024 EST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (30900) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 314) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x3037) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   253   253   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       7025
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       881
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   062   061   000    Old_age   Always       -       28303
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       84
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       63
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       817
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   110   104   000    Old_age   Always       -       42
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Should I be concerned? (And why is it only performing at 3Gb/s?)

Comment: Re the `BadCRC` message, see https://superuser.com/questions/641219/possibly-a-dying-hard-drive-but-reads-writes-work-unsure-about-log-entries/642771#642771

Comment: @sawdust Thanks!  That was extremely helpful.  If you want to formally answer the question, I'd love to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the information provided in @sawdust's comment, I was able to determine that the issue was a poor performing SATA cable.  Replacing the cable solved the problem and the errors have gone away.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).